# Upgrading Sequelize Package

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js

My App is using Sequelize npm package with version 4.22.7, Everything is fine, but when upgrading it to latest (5.21.7), I see one TypeError in my logs like

**export default class BaseModel extends sequelize.Model {
                                                 ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null**

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize v5 has breaking changes in comparison to v4. Read carefully about changes in v5 and how to migrate from v4 to v5 [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/upgrade-to-v5.html)

Comment: rule of thumb: check for all breaking changes and obsolete and deprecated features when you wish to upgrade ANY package to the next major version (sometimes the minor one too)